# problem with PDF image with acrofields in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext

He tried to change the button icon of a pdf already created, this is my code

```
 PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.forma));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,new FileOutputStream(destino+"/forma.pdf"));
        InputStream ims = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.forma);
        AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();
       // Log.e("Datos", acroFields.getFields()+"");
        PushbuttonField ad  = acroFields.getNewPushbuttonFromField("Firma1");
        Log.e("botones",ad.getField()+"");
        ad.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
        ad.setProportionalIcon(true);
        ad.setImage(Image.getInstance(ruta));

        acroFields.replacePushbuttonField("advertisement", ad.getField());
```

I do not get an error but I do not get the icon or the image, I appreciate the help in advance

Comment: Is it correct that you take the field "firma" as template for setting the field "advertisement"? And are both fields buttons? Please share the PDF in question for reproducing the issue.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem the field "advertisement" was badly named, forgive this awkward error